# Make a POST of form in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to make a post request with the Net::HTTP in Ruby. The website is like:

```
 <form method="post" action="login.php">
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="id" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    <td> <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Login" /> </td></tr>
 </form>
```

Following the example in Net::HTTP in Ruby, the ruby script is like:

```
 uri = URI('http://www.example.com/login.php')
 req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
 req.set_form_data('id' => 'myid', 'password' => 'mypassword', 'submit' => 'Login') 
 res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
     http.request(req)
 end
```

I assume `res` should be the page after login in, but the login is not sucessful. What is the problem?

Comment: Your post is OK.. only the things you missed to tell us what you found,when you ran your code.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the the full `res`, headers and body. Because I would not assume that the `res.body` is any other page. I would assume to see some cookie and a redirect in the header. And you have to handle that redirect yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "the login is not successful"? Does the response tell you "invalid password" or something? Or is the response as you think it should be, but you expect a subsequent request to be "logged in", but it isn't? In the latter case, do you carry the cookie to the next request? Maybe you should consider [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) instead.

Comment: I print the res.body, and it's still the login.php. And it seems that the password is not tested at all.